# php substr(string_name, start_position, string_length_to_cut)

Tags: php, substr

In `substr(string_name, start_position, string_length_to_cut)` what will happen, if i give `string_length_to_cut` greater than the `string_name` and why?

Comment: Read about [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php) and try it yourself in a [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/). Also, please, read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is outlined in the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). Example #3.

```
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
```

The extra length is simply replaced by blank space.